# Ignoring lines that start with # on PostgreSQL (CSV parsing)

Tags: postgresql, csv

How do I ignore lines that begin with # on a CSV file that I'm trying to copy into a table on PostgreSQL? Below is my existing SQL.

```
copy STAGING.RABC_SPEND
FROM ''' || fileinput || '''
WITH CSV HEADER
```

Comment: `copy` can't do that, you need to remove those lines manually before you can use the `copy` command

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres 9.3 and up, you could do this with [`COPY FROM PROGRAM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html), where the program string is some shell command which filters the file.

So, on Linux:

```
COPY STAGING.RABC_SPEND FROM 'grep -v ^# "/path/to/file"'
```

And on Windows:

```
COPY STAGING.RABC_SPEND FROM 'findstr /v /b # "C:\Path\To\File"'
```